# Call functions put in array

Tags: java, function

for my code in Java I need to call functions for some figures inside a number. In fact, if my number is 464, I have to call functions named assert4 and assert6. I hope that you're understanding. But if I'm right, we can't concatenate a string and a variable to have the name of a function and execute it. For example :

```
for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
    assert + i + (); // For example executing the function assert4
}
```

So I can't see how I can do it. Thanks for help !

Answer (score 2):

You *can* do this with reflection using something like `YourClass.class.getMethod(...).invoke(...)`. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string) for instance.)

However, this is a bit of a code smell and I encourage you to do something like

```
Map<Integer, Runnable> methods = new HashMap<>();
methods.put(464, YourClass::assert464);
...

for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
    methods.get(i).run();
}
```

---

If you're on Java 7 or older, the equivalent would be

```
methods.put(464, new Runnable() { public void run() { assert464(); } });
```

Comment: What version of Java is needed in your first code block?

Comment: Java 8. Released roughly a year ago.

Comment: Thank you ! I 've just a little problem because when I declare all my functions in a array and I try to access it with assertionArray[i] in the 'public void run' of your second method, it said me that 'i' is accessed from within inner class...

Comment: Right, so was that part of an error message? If so, what is the exact full error message? You may need to do `final int j = i;` right before using it in the inner class, and then refer to `j` instead of `i`.

Comment: It expect me to declare i as a final var but when I do it (in the beginning of the for loop I write 'final int j = i' and I write 'assertionsArray[j]' it say that it's not a statement...

Comment: No, you need to do `assertionsArray[j].run()`.

Comment: @Krili, please accept the answer that best addresses your question so we get a closure of this thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a method using a String name using the reflection API.

Here's some tutorials on how to get started:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-dyn0603/